# Help with low poly hair modeling!

Tags: modeling, hair

So I am trying to model the hair for this design ...

[image: 1]

... and am running into problems getting the basic form of it just to start. Any suggestions for the best way to go about modeling? Should I start with curves or meshes or both?

Comment: I'm far from an expert, but with a hairstyle like that, you may be able to get away with deforming a cube or icosahedron +/- subdivide modifier. (I usually use Curves method myself, and so know little of the method I an suggesting.)

Comment: I don't know much about low poly but I would have just add a cube and deform it with loop cuts with a that reference image on background .